# Retrieve Instance of ActionExecutingContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to retrieve the instance of ActionExecutingContext inside of

> public ActionResult Contact2(string one, string two)

and not in the class albumAttribute.

Is it possible to do it?

Thanks![image]

```
        [HttpPost]
        [album]
        public ActionResult Contact2(string one, string two)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            var ss = Response.Status;

            var genres = new List<Genre>
            {
                new Genre { Name = "Disco"},
                new Genre { Name = "Jazz"},
                new Genre { Name = "Rock"}
            };
            //return View(genres);


            //return View("contact2", genres);

            return View("contact22", genres);
        }





    public class albumAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {

            HttpRequestBase req = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
            HttpResponseBase res = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

             UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder("http://" + req.Url.Authority + req.Url.LocalPath);
             NameValueCollection query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
             query.Add("album", "first");
             uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();

             string url = req.Url.AbsolutePath.ToString();
             res.Redirect(uriBuilder.Uri.OriginalString);

             base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

             /*
                UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder("http://" + req.Url.Authority + "/Home/About");
                res.Redirect(uriBuilder.Uri.OriginalString);

                base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
            */     

        }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you planing to do with it? If you need to get Request and Response objects they are directly accessible as Controller properties

Comment: In a simple explaination, it has to do with algorithm from a big project. This project in this thread is a simple sample of the big project.

Comment: I would like the code inside of albumattribute to be activated inside of actionresult contact2 but I cannot find the instance of ActionExecutingContext inside of ActionResult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments:

Action filters execute prior to Actions so inside an Action you won't be able to use `base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext)`.

Other than that all the code that's attached in the image could be executed without `ActionExecutingContext` object, just add it to your Action and for getting a Request and Response objects use `Response` and `Request` controller properties.
You can also use

```
return this.Redirect(yourUrl);
```

instead of `res.Redirect(...)`

```
    [HttpPost]
    [album]
    public ActionResult Contact2(string one, string two)
    {
        var req = this.Request;
        var res = this.Response;

        UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder("http://" + req.Url.Authority + req.Url.LocalPath);
        NameValueCollection query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
        query.Add("album", "first");
        uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();

        string url = req.Url.AbsolutePath.ToString();
        return this.Redirect(uriBuilder.Uri.OriginalString);            
    }
```

Comment: If you post your code (not as image) I can modify it to show you waht exactly I meant in the answer