# Redirect To Link OnActionExecuting (ActionExecutingContext)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint

Salaamun Alekum
I Want To Override

[Controller.OnActionExecuting Method (ActionExecutingContext)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

And Inside This Method I Want To RedirectTo WebPage Link How To Make It Possible

Example:

```
public class LicenseFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        ///Some Code Here
        Redirect("http://webpage.com"); ///Redirect to This Page 
        ///Rest Of The Code
```

Thank You Please Tell Me If You Require Further Details

Comment: Check out the answer in this post: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29912430/retrieve-instance-of-actionexecutingcontext][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29912430/retrieve-instance-of-actionexecutingcontext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're close but instead of the redirect try

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("http://www.webpage.com");
```

that's what I use anyways. Usually it's redirecting to my login page which would be on the same project so I would do something like

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(Url.Action("Index", "Login"));
```

*edit: removed return statements, it's a void and you only need to set the redirect result not return it*